# Economic interpretation of assumption on utility function

Tags: utility, consumer-theory, production-function, consumption

Suppose $u\colon \mathbb{R}_{>0} \to \mathbb{R}$ is a utility function, twice continously differentiable, $u' > 0, u'' < 0$, and the classic Inada conditions hold, i.e., $\lim_{c \to \infty} u'(c) = 0$ and $\lim_{c \to 0} u'(c) = \infty$.

**The question:** How could an additional assumption, that there exists $\beta > 0$ such that $u'(x)u'(y) \ge \beta u'(xy)$ holds for all $x,y > 0$, be interpreted economically?

Surely, a lot of classic production functions fulfill this, \eg, CRRA functions, $\sqrt c$, $\log(c)$, scaled versions of those and so on.

Functions that do not fulfill this have to be very steep when function values tend to zero, e.g., $u'(c) = e^{1/c}$ (where $u$ is given by the exponential integral function Ei), compare the related mathematical question on [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/425387/positive-monotone-decreasing-function-with-limit-in-0-equal-to-%e2%88%9e-submultiplica).

---